# Почему считают повествованием?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему данную фразу считают повествованием. Ведь здесь явное указание на мыслительную деятельность, возможность совершения действия (ничего не стоило)

> (27)Ему ничего не стоило без усилия и разбега вспрыгнуть на стол,
> перескочить через  кресло. (28)Ему не сиделось на одном месте,
> неожиданно для самого себя он вскакивал и  ронял книгу, менял место.

Answer (score 0):

Один из признаков повествования — наличие сюжета и цепочки событий.

В предложении 28 как раз-таки есть эта цепочка событий.

Comment: Но ведь повествование должно быть и там, и там.

Comment: А как звучит задание?

Comment: Определить тип речи, представленный в этих предложениях.